# Script help: giving the user the option to delete a file in the home directory then creates a log of deleted files

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a script that lists all files over 20000Mb in the home directoy.
This is what I have so far

> $ find $HOME -size -500b

I now want it to give the user to delete these files and to create a log of the deleted files.

Any commands to try?

Thanks

Comment: Look at `-ok` to give the user an option to delete, and `-printf` to write a message you can log

Comment: So like this? 
find $HOME -size -500b -ok -delete

to give the user the option to delte

Comment: Pay heed to `man find` concerning `-delete`: **Warnings:**  Don't forget that the `find` command line is evaluated as an expression, so putting `-delete` first will make find try to delete everything below the starting points you specified.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to watch out for. First, if using `-ok`, remember it acts much like the `-exec` option to find and will expect a command to be specified in that format. Next, when specifying size, if you want files `20G` or larger, you will likely want to specify `-size 20G`, but be aware that `find` will round size up. (you may need to adjust accordingly). All considered, you are probably looking for something similar to:

```
 find "$HOME" -type f -size 20G -ok rm -v '{}' \; >> "$logfile"
```

Which will log the output from `rm -v` for each file deleted. Depending on the output you want, you can also rely on the `-i` interactive option to `rm`. So an alternative would be:

```
 find "$HOME" -type f -size 20G -exec rm -iv '{}' \; >> "$logfile"
```